# How to draw custom shapes in Qt with QPainter or QPainterPath using one shape or a group of shapes joined

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

How can I draw a shape like a tear? I need to draw without using more than one shape (an ellipse and a polygon) because QPen will draw for each shape. I need to join shapes to create a new one, or tell QT to join the border across both shapes, something like this:

[image: tear]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the shape you want to draw can be represented as a layering of other shapes, as with the image you've linked to, it's pretty easy to do:

First we need to build a `QPainterPath` to represent the outer edge of the shape. We build it by layering up simpler shapes; in the case of your example we need a circle and a square. Note the use of [`QPainterPath::setFillRule(Qt::WindingFill)`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qpainterpath.html#setFillRule): this will later affect the way that the path is painted (try removing it to see the difference!).

```
QPainterPath OuterPath;
OuterPath.setFillRule(Qt::WindingFill);
OuterPath.addEllipse(QPointF(60, 60), 50, 50);
OuterPath.addRect(60, 10, 50, 50);
```

With the example you've given we'll also need to remove a circular area from the centre of our filled shape. Let's represent that inner 'border' as a `QPainterPath` and then use [`QPainterPath::subtracted()`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qpainterpath.html#subtracted) to subtract `InnerPath` from `OuterPath` and produce our final shape:

```
QPainterPath InnerPath;
InnerPath.addEllipse(QPointF(60, 60), 20, 20);

QPainterPath FillPath = OuterPath.subtracted(InnerPath);
```

Once we've built the shape paths, we need to use them to fill/outline the shape. Let's first create a `QPainter` and set it to use antialiasing:

```
QPainter Painter(this);
Painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
```

We then need to fill the shape that we've built:

```
Painter.fillPath(FillPath, Qt::blue);
```

Finally, let's paint the outlines. Note that, because we have separate paths for the inner and outer borders, we are able to stroke each border with different line thicknesses. Note also the use of [`QPainterPath::simplified()`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qpainterpath.html#simplified): this converts the set of layered shapes into one `QPainterPath` which has no intersections:

```
Painter.strokePath(OuterPath.simplified(), QPen(Qt::black, 1));
Painter.strokePath(InnerPath, QPen(Qt::black, 3));
```

---

If we put all of that together, it looks like this:

```
void Shape::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
  QPainterPath OuterPath;
  OuterPath.setFillRule(Qt::WindingFill);
  OuterPath.addEllipse(QPointF(60, 60), 50, 50);
  OuterPath.addRect(60, 10, 50, 50);

  QPainterPath InnerPath;
  InnerPath.addEllipse(QPointF(60, 60), 20, 20);

  QPainterPath FillPath = OuterPath.subtracted(InnerPath);

  QPainter Painter(this);
  Painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

  Painter.fillPath(FillPath, Qt::blue);
  Painter.strokePath(OuterPath.simplified(), QPen(Qt::black, 1));
  Painter.strokePath(InnerPath, QPen(Qt::black, 3));
}
```

Comment: amazing thats was my problem, the setFillRule, i did thought to use an ellipse and rect too but they create a white space between, i also think use to an arc and two lines for draw this, strokePath and fillPath was too wath i'm searching too, this solution si the most simple and usefull, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is actually quite difficult to do without a good math background. If you knew the formula to create that shape, you could just put it into your `QGraphicsItem::paint()` function. But there are some alternatives:

1. Make the image in a vector editing program like Inkscape (free), save it as a .svg file, and then load it into a [QGraphicsSvgItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicssvgitem.html). (This is what I would do.)
2. Have a look at [QPainterPath::cubicTo()](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qpainterpath.html#cubicTo), which allows you to make a Bezier curve

Comment: when a shape like the one cited by the OP can be represented as a layering of simple shapes, there's no need to use complex maths in order to represent it. Just layer simple shapes and use some of the features built into `QPainterPath` to build your complex shape. See my answer for details.